# recv stalls or does not return all data (C code)

Tags: c, sockets, recv, winsockets

I have a web service written in .net on a remote computer with IIS, I am trying to connect to it with a C program using socker to do a SOAP request.

My problem is that I have some probem receiving the data:

The receiving data loop does not work in a way or in another.

If I write:

```
nByte = 1;
while(nByte!=512)
{
   nByte = recv(sockfd,buffer,512, 0);
   if( nByte < 0 )
   {
      // check the error
   }
   if( nByte > 0)
   {
      // append buffer to received data
   }
}
```

sometime does not return all data, if it run without debugger and breackpoints.

If I try: `while(nByte!=0)` at the end of data it stalls and go in error.

How is it supposed to be done?
Thanks,
Antonino

** ***EDIT*** **
I resolved my situation in another way, I check the returned value for soap xml end:

```
nByte = 1;
while(nByte!=0)
{
   nByte = recv(sockfd,buffer,512, 0);
   if( nByte < 0 )
   {
      // check the error
   }
   if( nByte > 0)
   {
      // append nByte buffer to received data
      if( strstr("</soap:Envelope>", buffer) != NULL)
        break;
   }
}
```

It is very sad...

Answer (score 3):

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 512  

byte buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
int nByte = BUFFERSIZE;
int rByte;  

while(nByte!=0)
{
   rByte = recv(sockfd, &buffer[BUFFERSIZE-nByte], nByte, 0);
   if( rByte < 0 )
   {
      // socket error
      break;
   }
   if( rByte == 0)
   {
      // connection closed by remote side or network breakdown, buffer is incomplete
      break;
   }
   if(rByte>nByte)
   {
     // impossible but you must check it: memory crash, system error
     break;
   }
   nByte -= rByte;  // rByte>0 all is ok
   // if nByte==0 automatically end of loop, you read all
   // if nByte >0 goto next recv, you need read more bytes, recv is prtialy in this case
} 

//**EDIT**   

if(nByte!=0) return false;

// TO DO - buffer complete
```

Comment: in this way it receives only READSIZE bytes, I want it download all stream until connection closed, but It never return 0.

Comment: "in this way it receives only READSIZE bytes" - not, we probe read all, but not always socket return all and we must read more

Comment: in my answer, without errors you read all automatically and go out from loop without probe read 0 bytes. if rByte==0 and you not read all (nByte>0) - conection is closed by the remote side while communication, its incomplete connection.

Comment: I'v rename READSIZE to BUFFERSIZE

Comment: The state you label as impossible is indeed impossible. It is therefore unnecessary to check for it.

Comment: programmer must check all paths, no bad data only bad alghoritms exists

Answer (score 1):

Where does it say it fills the buffer? Read the *man* image. It blocks until at least one byte of data can be transferred, then transfers whatever data has arrived.